# CSV ingestion error in Azure Data Bricks - File read error

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

My task is to perform data ingestion of CSV file using python. I am using the following code block and getting error of `file not found` eventhough the location is right.

```
spark.read.format("Filelocation") \
  .option("file.format", "csv") \
  .option("file.schemaLocation", "checkpoint") \
  .load("source_data") \
  .writeStream \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .option("My_Checkpoint", "Checkpoint path") \
  .start("target")
```

I have no clue of the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple read statement error that I have observed from your code block.

```
spark.readStream.format("Filelocation")
```

Use the above code block in the first line instead of `spark.read.format("Filelocation")` and remaining statements are as it is.

Comment: Just now I have found the same reason for my question, You too delivered the same. Thanks for the answer @SairamTadepalli-MT